# can't start superset with docker compose

Tags: apache-superset

I don't seem to be able to start superset as per instructions.

```
tim@tim-home:~/repos/superset$ docker-compose -f docker-compose-non-dev.yml pull
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 699, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 394, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1282, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1328, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1277, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1037, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 975, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/docker/transport/unixconn.py", line 30, in connect
    sock.connect(self.unix_socket)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

This is after new install of docker-desktop (just now) and using git to obtain superset source.
cd to superset folder and run command as above

Any suggestions?

I also get the same result with sudo

Answer (score 0):

I went through a complete reinstall of docker and it worked, so I think a docker problem not superset